# How to handle multiple user save games of a RPG in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I have a complex RPG video game under development and it supports multiplayers, matchmaking, and cloud save game. For a lot of reasons, we are handling the "cloud save" ourselves - mainly for cross platform support.

For this, we created a SQL database on our servers, and for now we have a "users" table handling the different login, password, save, Steam/PlayStation/etc ID, and anything unique to a user. We have a "saves" table, and that's where I feel we can improve. The table definition looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE saves (
  id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  edit_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  data text NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The place I feel is lacking the `data text NOT NULL`, where right now we simply feed a Json'ed of a save game. In a RPG, a player may have an inventory, a number of quests, different NPC dialog states and so on. However, from what I understand there is no "clean" way of doing arrays inside a table cell in SQL. Having each saves game being in a different table would be terrible, as we could end up with tens or hundreds of tables.

Is there something we are overlooking, or is using a cell to store a serialized version of the save data the best I can do in SQL?

Comment: You have the option of storting json data into your database. Otherwise almost all of the database have support for storing xml.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph : I know, that's what I said I was doing. Is there a way to store Json other than by a "text" data type? But my goal was to not just dumb a huge string and go "That's the data" and be more "This cell holds the inventory, this cell holds the stats, this cell holds the quests". I assume this is impossible?

Comment: It is possible to create user defined type and store it in the database table. The user defined type would contain the attributes. See an example in oracle database : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/object-views-and-nested-tables

Comment: You could use either XML or JSON and build SQL views to give you an easy query mechanism. In a way expand the json into relational view.  It might not be the most performant. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/09/create-relational-view-over-json-text/.

Comment: @Akrion That's just for views, no? I still need to store the data as a string?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Sadly, OBJECT isn't available in MS SQL as far as I can figure out. Otherwise, that would have been great, especially if you can nest one into another.

Comment: @LightStriker the data files should be `nvarchar(max)` for storing JSON

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product - every relational database is a "SQL database". Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...